# comparing entered password to stored password(converts to sha254)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to complete a project where when you sign up it allows you to create a password, which is than stored in a file that will be read of when it comes to time to logging in (password is stored as a hash and when the user enters their password it is hashed to be compared to the stored text.) I am having issues however comparing the hashed password to the stored password. It seems no matter what i change the two strings never match. 
(Where the entered password has is compared to the stored password hash is on line 38.)

The code:

```
import hashlib

login_or_signup = input("Would You like to login or signup? ")
f = open("hashed_password_list.txt", "r")
print(f.read())

#SIGNUP PHAZE---------------------------------------------------

if login_or_signup == "signup":
  username = input("What is your name? ")
  password_sign_up = input("Enter your desired password: ")
  hash_object = hashlib.sha256(password_sign_up.encode('utf-8'))
  hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
  #print(hex_dig)

  pw2 = input("confirm password: ")
  hash_object = hashlib.sha256(pw2.encode('utf-8'))
  hex_dig2 = hash_object.hexdigest()
  #print(hex_dig2)
  if hex_dig == hex_dig2:
    print("the passwords match! Thanks for creating an accout with us, " + username)
    text = hex_dig 
    saveFile = open('hashed_password_list.txt', 'w')
    saveFile.write(text)
    saveFile.close()
  else:
    print("sorry the passwords did not match.")

#LOGIN PHAZE---------------------------------------------------

elif login_or_signup == "login":
  password_sign_up2 = input("Enter your password: ")
  hash_object2 = hashlib.sha256(password_sign_up2.encode('utf-8'))
  hex_dig2 = hash_object2.hexdigest()
  #print(hex_dig)

  #CHECK PASSWORD---------------------------------------------
  if f == hex_dig2:
  #print(info)
    print("succesfully logged in! ")
    f.close()
  else:
    print("The password you entered did not match our database please create an account")

#IF USER ENTERS WRONG COMMAND AT BEGINNING----------------------

else:
  print("error!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that:

```
f = open("hashed_password_list.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

The comparison:

```
if f == hex_dig2:
```

is wrong because you are comparing the return of `open`, that is a file object, with the string `hex_dig2`.

This is what you want:

```
if f.read() == hex_dig2:
```

but remember to comment out the line `print(f.read())`, otherwise the first read will consume the file content.

Since this is just a starting point for your use case, consider the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for managing file resources, for example:

```
with open("hashed_password_list.txt", "r") as f:
    if f.read() == hex_dig2:
        print(info)
        print("Successfully logged in! ")
    else:
        print("The password you entered did not match our database please create an account")
```

Comment: Thank, Worked great :)